# Push Notification in iPad not appear in Setting

Tags: iphone, ipad, settings, push-notification

I am working on push notification on iPad. My application is a universal application include iPhone and iPad. The iPhone push notification works well, the user receives push, the app name appears in the `Setting -> Notifications`

However, I have a small issue with the ipad version is that the app name does not appear in the list of `Settings -> Notifications`. I can still register for the device ID, the iPad does receive the push notification.

Does anyone know what can be a reason? I checked and be sure that both the registering code for both devices are exactly the same

Comment: try restarting the device. That usually works.

Comment: how about creating a new provisioning certificate por the ipad and try whit that see if that workes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is obvious, but did you try to:

- Restart the iPad?
- Completely remove the App, create a clean build and run that build on the iPad?
- Try to install on another iPad? Is the issue also present on the other iPad?

Reinstalling a clean build and restarting the device should do the trick with the majority of strange problems like this one. If this is not resolving your problem it's very important to test on another iPad or completely reset your iPad.

This way you can see if there is something wrong in the iOS install itself. It sounds like this is the case, because push is working and the iPhone version is working fine.

By testing on another iPad you could determine if the problem is in your code/App or in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Is your iPad updated to the latest version?

Follow the steps mentioned below.
http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad_Guide/ss/How-To-Turn-Off-Push-Notifications-On-The-Ipad.htm

Comment: The problem is my application already registered for the notifications but I cannot see it in the list app in the Setting--> Notifications view. I can see other apps working well

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are registering your app at launch time?

I had a similar issue where I removed `- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` by accident.

All the devices on which I had the application before removing that line still had the settings, but the new one didn't register to push hence not being registered in Settings.